# PHP if condition with date wordpress widget

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I have a date of updated posts `$date` which is printing the date as "November 3, 2018"

And I have a widget that should be shown only if the date is before October 29, 2018

I thave ried something like this for example:

```
$date    = get_the_time( 'F j, Y', $ID );
$deadline = strtotime('2018-10-29');
if ($date > $deadline) {
    echo 'Yes';
} else {
    echo 'No';
}
```

Comment: Put `$date` in `strtotime()`

Comment: `if ( strtotime($date) > $deadline ) { // The post date is after the deadline }`

Comment: For some reason it's printing 'No' in every date case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to format the date as "Y-m-d" so :

```
$date    = get_the_time( "Y-m-d");
//var_dump(  strtotime($date));
$deadline = strtotime('2010-09-29');
//var_dump( $deadline);
if (strtotime($date) > $deadline) {
  echo 'Yes';
} else {
echo 'No';
}
```

Comment: Welcome! The key to the solution is the fact that you've used `strtotime` to convert the formatted date to a unix timestamp, for comparison with the _other_ unix timestamp :). While it may _also_ be required to alter the date format, it's most important to cast as a timestamp.  **Most importantly** - you have fundamentally changed the code in a way that **will not work**: `get_the_time` _requires_ the `$ID` variable to be passed in.  This is a WordPress function that is getting the date _from the post_, and needs the post ID.